# 6 Square image take up 100% of 500px and stay same size

Tags: html, css

It was pretty tough naming this question or even just trying to explain what I'm looking for, so I've created a [jsfille here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ku88bro/) that you can have a look at.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width"></div>
  <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
  <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
  <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
  <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
  <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
  <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.full-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height:100px;  
}
.photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 16%; // 100% divided by 6
}
```

So I have 6 square images that need to line up in a row in a container of 500px width. This width cannot be modified. So, I made the width of each image 16% (100% divided by 6). But what ends up happening now is that it's not filling up the entire container. Which is pretty clear compared to an element that **does** fill up the entire with. The alignment is completely out then.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

using `width: 16.6%;` is as close as it gets, but it still doesn't fill the container perfectly.

Comment: You mean it doesn't fill it vertically, right?

Comment: Actually 100 / 6 = 16.666666666666...., so specifying `width: 16%` will make gap

Comment: check this : https://jsfiddle.net/6ku88bro/1/   . Set `width : 16.66%`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ku88bro/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`calc()`](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) function to achieve your goal.

```
.photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(500px / 6);
}
```

Or set it to `16.666666666666666666666666666667%`

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/6ku88bro/2/)

Css

```
.container {
 width: 500px;
}
.full-width {
background: blue;
 width: 500px;
height:100px;  
}
.photo {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: calc(100% / 6);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options you can use **calc** and **flex**

**calc** looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.full-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
.photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width"></div>
  <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
</div>
```

**flex** looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}
.full-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
.container > .image {
  flex: auto;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="photo" src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and the css will be same...

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.full-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height:100px;  
}
.photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
    <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
    <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
    <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
    <img class="photo"src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52a131d3e4b0aec740d0eadf/5310dce6e4b0f37a89519ed4/5310e278e4b0f37a8951e472/1393615480087/4insta.png?format=original" />
  </div>
</div>
```